# Trying to build a function that receive a char array and see if it is a valid state

Tags: c, arrays

The instructor wants this function to do this:
A function that will receive a single string and test that string to see if it is a valid state abbreviation.

I think I have the right track. But my text file has full names for the states as well as the abbreviations. File is below. How would I only test the abbreviations.

Also is their a way i can pass the char array into this function and then to another char array inside the function? Because the way I have this set up, it is testing to see if *buf* is a state abbreviation. IF it isn't it prompts the user to change the char array. But i am trying to keep it all in the same function.

In short i don't know what i am doing. Code isn't being nice to me. A point in the right direction would be nice.

```
void get_state(char buf[])
{
    FILE *pFile;
    char buffer[40];
    char state_list[101][3];
    bool check_state = false;

    pFile = fopen("STATES.DAT", "r");
    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i = i++)
        {
            //get state
            fgets(state_list[i], 40, pFile);
            state_list[i][strlen(state_list[i]) - 1] = '\0';
            printf("\nstate = %s\n", state_list[i]);
            system("pause");
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 51; x++)
    {
        if (buf == state_list[x])
        {
            check_state = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            check_state = false;
        }
    }

    while (check_state == false)
    {
        printf("\nState wasn't entered right, re-enter State: ");
        gets_s(buffer);

        for (int x = 0; x < 101; x++)
        {
            if (buffer == state_list[x])
            {
                check_state = true;

                break;
            }
            else
            {
                check_state = false;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

file is this.

```
ALASKA
AK
ALABAMA
AL
ARKANSAS
AR
ARIZONA
AZ
CALIFORIA
CA
COLORADO
CO
CONNECTICUT
CT
DELAWARE
DE
FLORIDA
FL
GEORGIA
GA
HAWAII
HI
IOWA
IA
IDAHO
ID
ILLINOIS
IL
INDIANA
IN
KANSAS
KS
KENTUCKY
KY
LOUISIANA
LA
MASSACHUSETTS
MA
MARYLAND
MD
MAINE
ME
MICHIGAN
MI
MINNESOTA
MN
MISSOURI
MO
MISSISSIPPI
MS
MONTANA
MT
NORTH CAROLINA
NC
NORTH DAKOTA
ND
NEBRASKA
NE
NEW HAMPSHIRE
NH
NEW JERSEY
NJ
NEW MEXICO
NM
NEVADA
NV
NEW YORK
NY
OHIO
OH
OKLAHOMA
OK
OREGON
OR
PENNSYLVANIA
PA
RHODE ISLAND
RI
SOUTH CAROLINA
SC
SOUTH DAKOTA
SD
TENNESSEE
TN
TEXAS
TX
UTAH
UT
VIRGINIA
VA
VERMONT
VT
WASHINGTON
WA
WISCONSIN
WI
WEST VIRGINIA
WV
WYOMING
WY
```

Comment: Comparing strings with `==` doesn't do what you think it does; it's a pointer comparison, not a string comparison. You most likely want something like `strcmp`.

Comment: Since the state names and abbreviations are on alternate lines, you can read each line, and if it is longer than two characters (plus newline), you can ignore it, but if it is only two characters plus newline, you zap the newline and keep it.  Then you can compare input against the list of states.  Note that using multiple functions is a good idea; one function would load the list of state abbreviations, while another would be used to check whether the input is valid, while the `main()` function would coordinate the calls to these functions. You should probably read states until EOF, too.

Comment: `fgets(state_list[i], 40, pFile);` is a bad idea because `state_list[i]` only has length `3`. I assume you meant to read into `buffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all ... try using strcmp for string comparison,

```
const char* xyz =" i am not here";
if(strcmp(xyz, "i am here")==0){
}
```

Moreover, try separating the code piece by piece so that you may know which code is doing what. It is a bad practice to do everything in a single function, since ur function is doing more than one operation, I suggest u separate things out.

But seeing as u want it in a single function, I suggest u use Do While as it fits ur needs ...

Here is how you should do it,

1)Read the file
2)
Do
Check if it is a valid abbreviation( i don't see case sensitivity being handled there) 
using STRCMP... 
3) if it is not a valid
4) repeat.